# Some questions on convex sets.

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces

Are all bounded closed convex sets in a metric space $(M,d)$ compact? or if not are they complete?

The positive definite matrices form a convex set ([Why does a positive definite matrix defines a convex cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213625/why-does-a-positive-definite-matrix-defines-a-convex-cone)), do they also form a metric space? If so what is the metric? Are they complete or compact?

P.S.
I am trying to understand if interior point methods can be applied to non Euclidean convex sets.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of positive definite matrices of a given size is convex. To see this, let $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ be two positive definite matrices in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^n$ be any nonzero vector and $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf x^T\left[\lambda\mathbf A+(1-\lambda)\mathbf B\right]\mathbf x=\lambda \mathbf x^T\mathbf A\mathbf x+(1-\lambda)\mathbf x^T\mathbf B\mathbf x>0,
\end{align*}
since both quadratic forms are strictly positive (because $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are positive definite and $\mathbf x$ is not zero) and at least one of $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ is positive.

For a given $n$, you can conceive the set of positive definite matrices of size $n$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ after rearranging the elements of the matrices into vectors. You can use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ on the subspace of vectors thus extracted from positive definite matrices. This set is not compact, because there exist positive definite matrices with arbitrarily large elements (say, $m\mathbf I$, where $m>0$ and $I$ is the identity matrix), nor is it complete, as $(1/m)\mathbf I$ is positive definite for all $m\in\mathbb Z_+$, but the limit of such a sequence is the zero matrix. (However, the set of positive *semi*-definite matrices, view as a subspace, is complete, because it is closed.)

---

To see a counterexample for a bounded, closed, convex set that is not compact, consider any infinite set $M$ that is also a vector space, endowed with the discrete metric $d$. That is, for any $x,y\in M$, let $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if $x=y$,}\\1&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Then, $M$ is bounded (because the distance between any two points is at most $1$), convex (since $M$ is also a vector space), and closed (the whole space is always closed in any metric space), but $\{m\}_{m\in M}$ is an infinite collection of open sets (hint: in a discrete metric space, every set is open) whose union is $M$, but there is no finite subcollection whose union is still $M$ (because $M$ is infinite by assumption). Hence, $M$ is not compact.

Comment: Thanks. I added closed sets in the edit.

Comment: @triomphe All bounded and closed subsets of a Euclidean space are compact and vice versa. You don't even need convexity. In general, a subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is _complete_ and _totally_ bounded. Moreover, in any metric space, any compact set is closed and bounded (but the converse may not be true).

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't be more clear :) But I would like to clarify two points which I didn't ask in the question. So are matrices not objects of Euclidean space? I mean vectors are in Euclidean space aren't matrices ? Second one is, does interior point method hold regardless of compactness or completeness?

Comment: @triomphe Vectors are special matrices which have only one column (or one row) each. You can view matrices in several different ways. For example, if $\mathbf A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, then $\mathbf A$ can be viewed as a linear _function_ mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, since if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathbf A\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^m$. You can also view them as elements of a larger Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{m\cdot n}$ after you rearrange the elements to be a vector of $m\cdot n$ elements. It all depends on the context.

Comment: @triomphe P.S.: I'm wondering what you mean by “matrix space” in your original question. Is it meant to be “metric space” or “metric space defined on matrices?”

Comment: corrected it, thanks.