# The set of Positive Definite Matrices is a Convex Cone

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Why is it that the set of positive definite matrices is a convex cone? I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding this because through the definition of a cone, I am required to show that the conic combination belongs to the set $S$ ; $\forall$ $\theta$ $\geq 0$. But if I set $\theta = 0$ then will it not give a null matrix? If yes then it wont be positive definite anymore and will hence not belong to the set. Kindly let me know if my question doesnt make sense at any point, I'll try to elaborate my confusion more.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213625/why-does-a-positive-definite-matrix-defines-a-convex-cone

Comment: Often the definition of "convex cone" includes only positive scalars, which may resolve this issue. Different definitions of course are in use. If the zero matrix has to be in there by your definition of convex cone, I agree that this might be a problem.

Comment: Some authors (such as Rockafellar) just require a cone to be closed under strictly positive scalar multiplication.

Comment: Yeah my lecture slides for a convex optimization course say that for all theta >= 0, S++ i.e. set of positive definite matrices gives us a convex cone. I guess it needs to be strictly greater for this to make sense.

Comment: In my opinion, the cone of positive semi-definite matrices is more important, since this cone is closed. And the set of positive definite matrices is precisely the interior of the semi-definite matrices.